# How can Azure Service Bus client-side batching guarantee messages aren't lost?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, amqp

Azure Service Bus has a feature of "client-side batching" (implemented by protocols AMQP and SBMP). [I am reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk#client-side-batching) what the documentation says about it. It makes a rather bold claim: (emphasis mine)

> **There is no risk of losing messages with batching**, even if there is a Service Bus failure at the end of a 20ms batching interval.

How can this be true? If messages were sent synchronously, I'd know that after the "send" method returns, the message is already on the bus and I no longer need to worry about it. But if the purpose of client-side batching is to delay sending of the message for 20ms after the method returns, so that subsequent calls to this method can add messages to the same batch, then, at least in my mind, surely there *must* be a risk that something bad can happen within these 20ms and the whole batch will be lost.

The only possible workaround I can think of is if the batching happened on the server instead, but then the feature wouldn't be called *client*-side batching.

Is this claim true? Do I misunderstand that sentence, or what the client-side batching is meant to achieve? Or did clever people at Microsoft come up with a technical solution that hasn't occurred to me?

Comment: This doesn't seem like something the SO community can address, I'd recommenced contacting the Azure support team.

Comment: I actually have a theory, I think the mostly likely explanation is that the Task will only complete when the batch is sent but concurrent Tasks may be batched. Which would make it doubly important to use techniques such as Task.WhenAll for ASB operations. I can confirm it experimentally but I'll need to find a minute.

Answer (score 1):

The note that you are referring to is under `Batching store access` which is talking about batching on the service end, not the client.